# How do print HTML file or Image from android phone through HP ePrint App?

Tags: android

My Concept is want to take print from android app, I tried lot of way then finally i got some solution here, I tried to print HTML file with HP ePrint App. In this code we can sending text file or html file or image to HP ePrint APP for printing, But Text file is working fine. I want to send HTML file its not working. It's showing some error.

**MainActivity.java**

```
import java.io.File;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Picture;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Html;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

/**
 * Various print samples.
 */
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    String text = "private static final String  TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();";

    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    static final String HELLO_WORLD = "Hello World";


    /**
     * Called when the activity is first created.
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        //
        // check for and install Send 2 Printer if needed
        //

        if( PrintUtils.isSend2PrinterInstalled(this) == false )
        {
            PrintUtils.launchMarketPageForSend2Printer( this );
            return;
        }

        //
        // setup GUI buttons
        //

        Button btnTestCanvas = (Button)findViewById( R.id.btnTestCanvas );
        btnTestCanvas.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                printCanvasExample();
            }
        });

        Button btnTestCanvasAsBitmap = (Button)findViewById( R.id.btnTestCanvasAsBitmap );
        btnTestCanvasAsBitmap.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                printCanvasAsBitmapExample();
            }
        });

        Button btnTestText = (Button)findViewById( R.id.btnTestText );
        btnTestText.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                printTextExample();
            }
        });

        Button btnTestHtml = (Button)findViewById( R.id.btnTestHtml );
        btnTestHtml.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                printHtmlExample();
            }
        });

        Button btnTestHtmlUrl = (Button)findViewById( R.id.btnTestHtmlUrl );
        btnTestHtmlUrl.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                printHtmlUrlExample();
            }
        });

        Button btnTestTextFile = (Button)findViewById( R.id.btnTestTextFile );
        btnTestTextFile.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                printTextFileExample();
            }
        });

        Button btnTestHtmlFile = (Button)findViewById( R.id.btnTestHtmlFile );
        btnTestHtmlFile.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                printHtmlFileExample();
            }
        });
    }


    /**
     * Send canvas draw commands for printing.
     * NOTE: Android 1.5 does not properly support drawBitmap() serialize/deserialize across process boundaries.
     * If you need to draw bitmaps, then see the {@link #printCanvasAsBitmapExample()} example. 
     */
    void printCanvasExample()
    {
        // create canvas to render on
        Picture picture = new Picture();
        Canvas c = picture.beginRecording( 240, 240 );

        // fill background with WHITE
        c.drawRGB( 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF );

        // draw text
        Paint p = new Paint();
        Typeface font = Typeface.create(Typeface.SANS_SERIF, Typeface.BOLD);
        p.setTextSize( 18 );
        p.setTypeface( font );
        p.setAntiAlias(true);       
        Rect textBounds = new Rect();
        p.getTextBounds( HELLO_WORLD, 0, HELLO_WORLD.length(), textBounds );
        int x = (c.getWidth() - (textBounds.right-textBounds.left)) / 2;
        int y = (c.getHeight() - (textBounds.bottom-textBounds.top)) / 2;
        c.drawText( HELLO_WORLD, x, y, p );

        // draw icon
        Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource( getResources(), R.drawable.icon );
        c.drawBitmap( icon, 0, 0, null );

        // stop drawing
        picture.endRecording();

        // queue canvas for printing
        File f = PrintUtils.saveCanvasPictureToTempFile( picture );
        if( f != null )
        {
            PrintUtils.queuePictureStreamForPrinting( this, f );
        }
    }


    /**
     * Draw to a bitmap and then send the bitmap for printing.
     */
    void printCanvasAsBitmapExample()
    {
        // create canvas to render on
        Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap( 240, 240, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565 );
        Canvas c = new Canvas( b );

        // fill background with WHITE
        c.drawRGB( 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF );

        // draw text
        Paint p = new Paint();
        Typeface font = Typeface.create(Typeface.SANS_SERIF, Typeface.BOLD);
        p.setTextSize( 18 );
        p.setTypeface( font );
        p.setAntiAlias(true);       
        Rect textBounds = new Rect();
        p.getTextBounds( HELLO_WORLD, 0, HELLO_WORLD.length(), textBounds );
        int x = (c.getWidth() - (textBounds.right-textBounds.left)) / 2;
        int y = (c.getHeight() - (textBounds.bottom-textBounds.top)) / 2;
        c.drawText( HELLO_WORLD, x, y, p );

        // draw icon
        Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource( getResources(), R.drawable.icon );
        c.drawBitmap( icon, 0, 0, null );

        // queue bitmap for printing
        try
        {
            File f = PrintUtils.saveBitmapToTempFile( b, Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG );
            if( f != null )
            {
                PrintUtils.queueBitmapForPrinting( this, f, Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG );
            }
        }
        catch( Exception e )
        {
            Log.e( TAG, "failed to save/queue bitmap", e );
        }
    }


    /**
     * Send text for printing.
     */
    void printTextExample()
    {
        //CharSequence styledText = Html.fromHtml(text);
        PrintUtils.queueTextForPrinting( this, HELLO_WORLD );
    }


    /**
     * Send html for printing.
     */
    void printHtmlExample()
    {
        StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
        buf.append( "<html>" );
        buf.append( "<body>" );
        buf.append( "<h1>" ).append( HELLO_WORLD ).append( "</h1>" );           
        buf.append( "<p>" ).append( "blah blah blah..." ).append( "</p>" );  
        buf.append( "<p><img src=\"http://www.google.com/intl/en_ALL/images/logo.gif\" /></p>" );
        // you can also reference a local image on your sdcard using the "content://s2p_localfile" provider (see below) 
        //buf.append( "<p><img src=\"content://s2p_localfile/sdcard/logo.gif\" /></p>" );
        buf.append( "</body>" );            
        buf.append( "</html>" );

        PrintUtils.queueHtmlForPrinting( this, buf.toString() );
    }


    /**
     * Send html URL for printing.
     */
    void printHtmlUrlExample()
    {
        PrintUtils.queueHtmlUrlForPrinting( this, "http://www.google.com" );
    }


    /**
     * Send text file for printing.
     */
    void printTextFileExample()
    {
        try
        {
            //CharSequence styledText = Html.fromHtml(text);            
            File f = PrintUtils.saveTextToTempFile( HELLO_WORLD );
            if( f != null )
            {
                PrintUtils.queueTextFileForPrinting( this, f );
            }
        }
        catch( Exception e )
        {
            Log.e( TAG, "failed to save/queue text", e );
        }
    }


    /**
     * Send html file for printing.
     */
    void printHtmlFileExample()
    {
        try
        {
            StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
            buf.append( "<html>" );
            buf.append( "<body>" );
            buf.append( "<h1>" ).append( HELLO_WORLD ).append( "</h1>" );           
            buf.append( "<p>" ).append( "blah blah blah..." ).append( "</p>" );  
            buf.append( "<p><img src=\"http://www.google.com\" /></p>" );
            // you can also reference a local image on your sdcard using the "content://s2p_localfile" provider (see below) 
            //buf.append( "<p><img src=\"content://s2p_localfile/sdcard/logo.gif\" /></p>" );
            buf.append( "</body>" );            
            buf.append( "</html>" );

            File f = PrintUtils.saveHtmlToTempFile( buf.toString() );
            if( f != null )
            {
                PrintUtils.queueHtmlFileForPrinting( this, f );
            }
        }
        catch( Exception e )
        {
            Log.e( TAG, "failed to save/queue html", e );
        }
    }
}
```

**PrintUtils.java**

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Picture;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;


/**
 * Static methods to detect, install, and print to a network printer with Android.
 */
public class PrintUtils {
    static Activity myMainActivity;
    // for logging
    private static final String TAG = PrintUtils.class.getSimpleName();

    // Send 2 Printer package name
    private static final String PACKAGE_NAME = "com.hp.android.print";

    // intent action to trigger printing
    public static final String PRINT_ACTION = "org.androidprinting.intent.action.PRINT";

    // content provider for accessing images on local sdcard from within html content
    // sample img src shoul be something like "content://s2p_localfile/sdcard/logo.gif"
    public static final String LOCAL_SDCARD_CONTENT_PROVIDER_PREFIX = "content://s2p_localfile";


    /**
     * Returns true if "Send 2 Printer" is installed. 
     */
    public static boolean isSend2PrinterInstalled( Context context )
    {
        boolean output = false;
        PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
        try { 
            PackageInfo pi = pm.getPackageInfo( PACKAGE_NAME, 0 );
            if( pi != null )
            {
                output = true;
            }
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {}
        return output;
    }


    /**
     * Launches the Android Market page for installing "Send 2 Printer"
     * and calls "finish()" on the given activity.
     */
    public static void launchMarketPageForSend2Printer( final Activity context )
    {
        AlertDialog dlg = new AlertDialog.Builder( context )
        .setTitle("Install HP ePrint")
        .setMessage("Before you can print to a network printer, you need to install HP ePrinter from the Android Market.")
        .setPositiveButton( android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick( DialogInterface dialog, int which )
            {
                // launch browser
                Uri data = Uri.parse( "http://market.android.com/search?q=pname:" + PACKAGE_NAME );
                Intent intent = new Intent( android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, data );
                intent.setFlags( Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP );
                context.startActivity( intent );

                // exit
                context.finish();
            }
        } )
        .show();    
    }


    /**
     * Save the given picture (contains canvas draw commands) to a file for printing.
     */
    public static File saveCanvasPictureToTempFile( Picture picture )
    {
        File tempFile = null;

        // save to temporary file
        File dir = getTempDir();
        if( dir != null )
        {
            FileOutputStream fos = null;
            try
            {
                File f = File.createTempFile( "picture", ".stream", dir );
                fos = new FileOutputStream( f );
                picture.writeToStream( fos );
                tempFile = f;
            }
            catch( IOException e )
            {
                Log.e( TAG, "failed to save picture", e );
            }
            finally
            {
                close( fos );
            }
        }       

        return tempFile;
    }


    /**
     * Sends the given picture file (returned from {@link #saveCanvasPictureToTempFile}) for printing.
     */
    public static boolean queuePictureStreamForPrinting( Context context, File f )
    {
        // send to print activity
        Uri uri = Uri.fromFile( f );
        Intent i = new Intent( PRINT_ACTION );
        i.setDataAndType( uri, "application/x-android-picture-stream" );
        i.putExtra( "scaleFitToPage", true );
        context.startActivity( i );

        return true;
    }


    /**
     * Save the given Bitmap to a file for printing.
     * Note: Bitmap can be result of canvas draw commands.
     */
    public static File saveBitmapToTempFile( Bitmap b, Bitmap.CompressFormat format )
    throws IOException, UnknownFormatException
    {
        File tempFile = null;

        // save to temporary file
        File dir = getTempDir();
        if( dir != null )
        {
            FileOutputStream fos = null;
            try
            {
                String strExt = null;
                switch( format )
                {
                    case PNG:
                        strExt = ".pngx";
                        break;

                    case JPEG:
                        strExt = ".jpgx";
                        break;

                    default:
                        throw new UnknownFormatException( "unknown format: " + format );
                }
                File f = File.createTempFile( "bitmap", strExt, dir );
                fos = new FileOutputStream( f );
                b.compress( format, 100, fos );
                tempFile = f;
            }
            finally
            {
                close( fos );
            }
        }       

        return tempFile;
    }


    /**
     * Sends the given image file for printing.
     */
    public static boolean queueBitmapForPrinting( Context context, File f, Bitmap.CompressFormat format )
    throws UnknownFormatException
    {
        String strMimeType = null;
        switch( format )
        {
            case PNG:
                strMimeType = "image/png";
                break;

            case JPEG:
                strMimeType = "image/jpeg";
                break;

            default:
                throw new UnknownFormatException( "unknown format: " + format );
        }

        // send to print activity
        Uri uri = Uri.fromFile( f );
        Intent i = new Intent( PRINT_ACTION );
        i.setDataAndType( uri, strMimeType );
        i.putExtra( "scaleFitToPage", true );
        i.putExtra( "deleteAfterPrint", true );
        context.startActivity( i );

        return true;
    }


    /**
     * Sends the given text for printing.
     */
    public static boolean queueTextForPrinting( Context context, String strContent )
    {
        // send to print activity
        Intent i = new Intent( PRINT_ACTION );
        i.setType( "text/plain" );
        i.putExtra( Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, strContent );
        context.startActivity( i );

        return true;
    }


    /**
     * Save the given text to a file for printing.
     */
    public static File saveTextToTempFile( String text )
    throws IOException
    {
        File tempFile = null;

        // save to temporary file
        File dir = getTempDir();
        if( dir != null )
        {
            FileOutputStream fos = null;
            try
            {
                File f = File.createTempFile( "text", ".txt", dir );
                fos = new FileOutputStream( f );
                fos.write( text.getBytes() );
                tempFile = f;
            }
            finally
            {
                close( fos );
            }
        }       

        return tempFile;
    }


    /**
     * Sends the given text file for printing.
     */
    public static boolean queueTextFileForPrinting( Context context, File f )
    {
        // send to print activity
        Uri uri = Uri.fromFile( f );
        Intent i = new Intent( PRINT_ACTION );
        i.setDataAndType( uri, "text/plain" );
        i.putExtra( "deleteAfterPrint", true );
        context.startActivity( i );

        return true;
    }


    /**
     * Sends the given html for printing.
     * 
     * You can also reference a local image on your sdcard using the "content://s2p_localfile" provider.
     * For example: <img src="content://s2p_localfile/sdcard/logo.gif">
     */
    public static boolean queueHtmlForPrinting( Context context, String strContent )
    {
        // send to print activity
        Intent i = new Intent( PRINT_ACTION );
        i.setType( "text/html" );
        i.putExtra( Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, strContent );
        context.startActivity( i );

        return true;
    }


    /**
     * Sends the given html URL for printing.
     * 
     * You can also reference a local file on your sdcard using the "content://s2p_localfile" provider.
     * For example: "content://s2p_localfile/sdcard/test.html"
     */
    public static boolean queueHtmlUrlForPrinting( Context context, String strUrl )
    {
        // send to print activity
        Intent i = new Intent( PRINT_ACTION );
        //i.setDataAndType( Uri.parse(strUrl), "text/html" );// this crashes!
        i.setType( "text/html" );
        i.putExtra( Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, strUrl );
        context.startActivity( i );

        return true;
    }


    /**
     * Save the given html content to a file for printing.
     */
    public static File saveHtmlToTempFile( String html )
    throws IOException
    {
        File tempFile = null;

        // save to temporary file
        File dir = getTempDir();
        if( dir != null )
        {
            FileOutputStream fos = null;
            try
            {
                File f = File.createTempFile( "html", ".html", dir );
                fos = new FileOutputStream( f );
                fos.write( html.getBytes() );
                tempFile = f;
            }
            finally
            {
                close( fos );
            }
        }       

        return tempFile;
    }


    /**
     * Sends the given html file for printing.
     */
    public static boolean queueHtmlFileForPrinting( Context context, File f )
    {
        // send to print activity
        Uri uri = Uri.fromFile( f );
        Intent i = new Intent( PRINT_ACTION );
        i.setDataAndType( uri, "text/html" );
        i.putExtra( "deleteAfterPrint", true );
        //context.startActivity( i);
        myMainActivity.startActivityForResult(i, 0);
        //((Activity) context).startActivityForResult(i, 0);
        return true;
    }

   /*
    public static boolean queueTextFileForPrinting( Context context, File f )
    {
        // send to print activity
        Uri uri = Uri.fromFile( f );
        Intent i = new Intent( PRINT_ACTION );
        i.setDataAndType( uri, "text/plain" );
        i.putExtra( "deleteAfterPrint", true );
        context.startActivity( i );

        return true;
    }
    */

    /**
     * Return a temporary directory on the sdcard where files can be saved for printing.
     * @return null if temporary directory could not be created.
     */
    public static File getTempDir()
    {
        File dir = new File( Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "temp" );
        if( dir.exists() == false && dir.mkdirs() == false )
        {
            Log.e( TAG, "failed to get/create temp directory" );
            return null;
        }
        return dir;
    }


    /**
     * Helper method to close given output stream ignoring any exceptions.
     */
    public static void close( OutputStream os )
    {
        if( os != null )
        {
            try
            {
                os.close();
            }
            catch( IOException e ) {}
        }
    }


    /**
     * Thrown by bitmap methods where the given Bitmap.CompressFormat value is unknown.
     */
    public static class UnknownFormatException extends Exception
    {
        public UnknownFormatException( String msg )
        {
            super( msg );
        }
    }
}
```

**Log Error**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not initialized `myMainActivity` but are attempting to invoke a method on it:

```
myMainActivity.startActivityForResult(i, 0);
```